# SQL Apply Value to subsequent rows

Tags: sql, oracle

| PK | Field2 | Field3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | a1 | 0 00:05 |
| 11111 | a2 | 0 00:05 |
| 22222 | a1 | 0 00:05 |

I want to update ALL values in Field3 for '11111' to '0 00:10' only if a2 in Field2 is present. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `UPDATE` with an `EXISTS` filter condition:

```sql
UPDATE table_name t
SET field3 = '0 00:10'
WHERE pk = 11111
AND EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM   table_name x
  WHERE  t.pk     = x.pk
  AND    x.field2 = 'a2'
)
```

or a `MERGE` statement with a conditional analytic function:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT COUNT(CASE field2 WHEN 'a2' THEN 1 END) OVER () AS cnt
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  pk = 11111
) src
ON (dst.ROWID = src.ROWID AND src.cnt = 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET Field3 = '0 00:10';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (PK, Field2, Field3) AS
SELECT 11111, 'a1', '0 00:05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11111, 'a2', '0 00:05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22222, 'a1', '0 00:05' FROM DUAL;
```

Then, after the `UPDATE` or `MERGE`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | PK | FIELD2 | FIELD3 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 11111 | a1 | 0 00:10 |
> | 11111 | a2 | 0 00:10 |
> | 22222 | a1 | 0 00:05 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5309fe2ecff0a90567f659337a2b7bff)*

---

If you just want to use a `SELECT` statement then:

```sql
SELECT pk,
       field2,
       CASE
       WHEN pk = 11111
       AND  COUNT(CASE field2 WHEN 'a2' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY pk) > 0
       THEN '0 00:10'
       ELSE field3
       END AS field3
FROM   table_name;
```

or

```sql
SELECT pk,
       field2,
       CASE
       WHEN pk = 11111
       AND  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   table_name x
         WHERE  x.pk = t.pk
         AND    x.field2 = 'a2'
       )
       THEN '0 00:10'
       ELSE field3
       END AS field3
FROM   table_name t;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4b55874496c1fc5f4eb4827ccf563876)*

Comment: I would prefer not to alter table and do this task from the read-only account using regular dml. is there some sort of join i can use for this in the select clause?

Comment: @AlSol The question asks to "update ALL values" therefore you got an answer with an `UPDATE` DML statement; if you do not want to "update ALL values" then don't write "update" in the question as it will give people a misleading impression of your requirements. You do not need to use a `JOIN` either.

Comment: Thank you! That was it! Apologies for using 'update' in the question section.